# Click anywhere outside of toggle div to close

Tags: jquery

I've got a div sidebar with a toggle button which makes it slide out from the left. I've searched the web for a Jquery script that will allow me to close this sidebar from clicking anywhere on the webpage and can't find anything that will work for me.

Below is the existing jQuery i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.toggle_sidebar').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar_extended').toggle("500");
});
    });
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar_extended{
width:180px;
position:absolute;
min-height: 100%;
height:100%;
left:0;
margin:0 10px 0 0;
padding:0;
background:#3a3b3c; 
display: none;
z-index: 5000;
color: #fff;
text-indent: 10px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toggle">
  <a href="#sidebar_extended" class="toggle_sidebar">
    <img src="images/toggle.png" alt="toggle">
  </a>
</div>

<div id="sidebar_extended">
  Sidebar content
</div>
```

Comment: post all relevant code please.

Comment: Try copying that code and using `body` as the selector instead of `.toggle_sidebar`

Comment: Added the HTML/CSS above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3scfbfdd/1/

Comment: That's excellent thank you Arun.

Answer (score 0):

For the hide part, try this :

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
  if (e.target.id != "sidebar_extended"){
    $('#sidebar_extended').toggle("500");
  }
}
```

For an even more powerful solution, please take a look at this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385673/644669

Comment: The code from that link does work but it removes the toggle effect from the "toggle_sidebar" link.

Comment: The code above is intended to be integrated in your code.